# After using eclipse from adt, error creating pure java project, on mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I'm using a MAC and I downloaded the latest adt for android development on MAC.

I am able to create android projects smoothly, however I can't create a pure Java Project.

I get this error after creating a java project:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Unbound classpath container:
>   'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]' in project 'dfs'    dfs     Build
>   path  Build Path Problem

My java version is 1.6.0_65.

I want to stress that I can create android applications, but NOT regular, Java projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in 'Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments'. Click on JavaSE-1.6 and select a JRE in the 'Compatible JREs' section.

You may also need to check in 'Preferences > Java > Installed JREs' that Eclipse knows about the Java 1.6

Comment: first off thank you for your response. 
As you wrote in the second sentance, when I click on JavaSE-1.6, in "Ececution Environments", the "Compatible JRE's" is empty, how do I make Eclipse "know about the java 1.6"

Comment: What do you have in `Installed JREs'?

Comment: I have nothing. sorry for not mentioning that. I googled a little after you posted the question, and did Add->Standard VM-> and in JRE Home, I pushed "Directory", however in the "Library" folder, there is no "Java" folder, I remind you I'm using mac

Comment: For Java 1.6 look in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions later versions of Java are in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. If you have upgraded to Yosemite the Java 1.6 get deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just want to stress that you wrote the path is "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines", and that the fulll path is "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home"